# Replacing empty texts - text embedding

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-classification, fasttext

I am trying to embed texts, using pre-trained fastText models. Some are empty. How would one replace them to make embedding possible? I was thinking about replacing them with dummy words, like that (docs being a pandas DataFrame object):
        `docs = docs.replace(np.nan, 'unknown', regex=True)`

However it doesn't really make sense as the choice of this word is arbitrary and it is not equivalent to having an empty string.

Otherwise, I could associate the 0 vector embedding to empty strings, or the average vector, but I am not convinced either would make sense, as the embedding operation is non-linear.

Answer (score 2):

In FastText, the sentence embedding is basically an average of the word vectors, as is shown in one of the [FastText papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01759.pdf):

[image: FastText figure]

Given this fact, zeroes might a logical choice. But, the answer depends on what you want to do with the embeddings.

If you use them as an input for a classifier, it should be fine to select an arbitrary vector as a representation of empty string and the classifier will learn what that means. FastText also learns a special embedding for `</s>`, i.e., end of a sentence. This is another natural candidate for an embedding of the empty string, especially if you do similarity search.